# Form with user added rows, and input element lookups on each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kc4fes2w/3/

In the linked fiddle I need to make it so that:

1. Right now on line 28, `lookup_arr[fm.user_entered_1.value]`, the name of the input element is actually just `lookup_arr[fm.user_entered_1.value]`, but it needs to become `lookup_arr[fm.user_entered_2.value]`, `lookup_arr[fm.user_entered_3.value]`, `lookup_arr[fm.user_entered_4.value]`, etc. as more rows get added and removed by the user, so that the lookup div can show the description for the user entered value on each row, not just the first row. I have a variable called `rowCount` in the fiddle which should contain the correct number on each row, however I can't seem to incorporate it.
2. In addition, I need to make it so that upon a user's change to the `user_entered_value_x` inputs, the corresponding descriptions get reloaded. For example in the Fiddle if `XXX` is changed to `YYY`, the description should change to `bunch of Ys` on that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at what i think you are trying to accomplish. I obviously changed a bunch of code but added notes trying to explain everything.

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/kc4fes2w/5/

I removed the tr with id = addedRows and moved the id to the table since we dont want to add a row to a row.

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1px" id="addedRows"></table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var lookup_arr = new Array();
lookup_arr['XXX'] = ' bunch of Xs ';
lookup_arr['YYY'] = ' bunch of Ys ';

function addMoreRows(frm) {
        var recRow = '<tr><td width="200px;"><input /></td> <td width="200px;"><div></div></td> <td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow(this);">Delete this Row</a> </td> </tr>';

        //add new row and return the jQuery object for it
        var tr = $('#addedRows').append(recRow).find('tr:last');
        //collection of td in the newly added row
        var tds = tr.find('td');
        //find dynamically added input
        var input = tds.eq(0).find('input');
        //set value for new item based off previous rows input value
        var prevInput = tr.prev().find('td').eq(0).find('input');
        input.val(prevInput.val());

        //add description to item based off input value
        tds.eq(1).html(lookup_arr[input.val()]);

        //add handler to update description based off input value
        input.on('input paste', function () {
            $this = $(this);
            var exists = lookup_arr[this.value]
            if (exists) {
                $this.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html(lookup_arr[this.value])
            } else {
                $this.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html('not found')
            }

        })
    }

    function removeRow(el) {
        $(el).closest('tr').remove();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Does everything I want functionally w/ the form. I have very little knowledge of JS though; in your code when the form gets submitted what are the names of each row's posted input value? The code I'm currently using to process the form relies on a row number being attached to each input name. Also on my real page I have other input elements on each row of the form (I boiled down the example for the specific problems I couldn't solve myself).

Comment: Another issue is that on my actual page I have a few inputs on each row that each need to have such a lookup. I thought I'd be able to expand upon an answer to this question myself but like I said I don't know much JS and I think this relies on there being just one input on each row of the form? Is there a way to name the input (so as to allow other inputs on each row) while retaining the same functionality?

Comment: Will mark this is the answer though as it obviously answers the particular question at hand.

Comment: You can add names to the inputs however when i'm access them i'm doing it based off their position. eq(0) means the 1st item that is returned from the td collection (actually a jquery object) tds.eq(0).find('input'), just one of the many ways to access the element. If you want to attach names so when you serialize the form you can certainly do that stepping them up with each rowCount like you were doing.

Comment: I think I'm getting the hang of it. Will post a new question if I can't figure out some of the last pieces. Thanks again :)